# Remove Duplicates linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

```
void RemoveDuplicates(Slist& l)
{
    if (l.head == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    Node* cur = l.head;
    while (cur != NULL && cur->next != NULL) {
        Node* prev = cur;
        Node* temp = cur->next;
        while (temp != NULL) {
            if (temp->data == cur->data) {
                prev->next = temp->next;
                cur->next = prev->next;
                temp = prev->next;
            }
            else {
                prev = prev->next;
                temp = temp->next;
            }
        }
        cur = cur->next;
    }
}
```

Hi, I want to remove duplicates from linked list (0 is NULL)

```
input:  1->2->2->4->2->6->0 
outPut: 1->2->4->6->0
```

Result after I run my program is:

```
1->2->6
```

Where am I wrong? Please help me

Comment: Where is the allocated memory for nodes deleted?

Comment: Show the list definition. For example it is unclear whether you defined a pointer to the tail node.

Comment: You should use a debugger and in addition visualize each step using on paper, so see what happens. You have `cur` which does not change in the inner loop where you search for the duplicates, but you also have `cur->next = prev->next` when you find a duplicate, and that cannot be right.

Comment: First, you probably didn't think about the problem long enough. You want to remove the `2` which is after the `4`, because there is some `2` before the `4`. That means you need to compare _**non-adjacent**_ nodes. Did you notice that...? IMHO you can handle it in at least two ways: 1. You can walk through the whole list, and for each node 'c' still being in the list scan all the remaining nodes and remove those equal to the current 'c'. This has a square complexity. 2. Or sort the whole list first (this phase has log-linear complexity), then scan for and remove adjacent duplicates (linear).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for your problem:

```
bool alreadyExist(Node head)
{
    Node cur = head;
    while(cur.next != nullptr)
    {
        if(cur.next->data == head.data) {
            return true;
        }
        cur = *cur.next;
    }

    return false;
}

void RemoveDuplicates(Slist& l)
{
    if (l.head == nullptr) {
        return;
    }

    Node* head = l.head;

    Node* curPtr = l.head->next;
    while(curPtr != nullptr)
    {
        if(alreadyExist(*curPtr) == false)
        {
            head->next = curPtr;
            head->next->prev = head;
            head = head->next;
            curPtr = curPtr->next;
        }
        else
        {
            Node* backup = curPtr;
            curPtr = curPtr->next;

            // delete duplicate elements from the heap,
            // if the nodes were allocated with new, malloc or something else
            // to avoid memory leak. Remove this, if no memory was allocated
            delete backup;
        }
    }
}
```

Important: The destructor of the Node-object is NOT allowed to delete the linked object behind the next and prev pointer.

It results, for your input-example, in the output `1->4->2->6->0`. Its not totally exact the order, you want as output, but each number exist only one time within the output. It only add the last time of a duplicate number.
I don't really know, if you use C or C++, but because I prefer C++, I replaced the NULL with nullptr in the code. The delete can be removed, if the objects are not on the HEAP create with malloc or new.

Comment: Thank you Everyone . This morning I fixed my problem ^^. Thank for your help